# How to fadeIn and fadeOut elements in one div after defined time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to display queued messages one after another with delay in the same div? Current solution is bad because is showing instantly new divs.

HTML:

```
<div id="alert-bar-container"></div>
<button id="show">First message</button>
<button id="next">Next message</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var timeout;
$("#show").click(function () {
    alertBar("this appears first");
});
$("#next").click(function () {
    alertBar("this should wait and show after first disappeared");
});
function alertBar(msg) {
    var message_span = $('<span />').html(msg);
    var wrap_bar = $('<div />').addClass('alert_bar');
    $('#alert-bar-container').html(wrap_bar.append(message_span).hide());
    clearTimeout(wrap_bar.data("timer"));
    wrap_bar.clearQueue();
    if (wrap_bar.filter(":hidden").length == 1) wrap_bar.fadeIn('fast');
    wrap_bar.data("timer", setTimeout(function () {
        wrap_bar.fadeOut("slow");
        wrap_bar.remove();
    }, 2500));
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LsRK8/

Comment: you want to fade div on its own or on click of button?

Comment: On its own. Even when many times function is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="msg active">first</div>
    <div class="msg">second</div>
    <div class="msg">third</div>
    <div class="msg">fourth</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var active = $("#container").find(".active");
    var i = $(active).index();
    var len = $("#container").find(".msg").length;
    var next;
    if(i == (len-1)){
        next = $("#container").find(".msg:first");
    }
    else{
        next = $("#container").find(".msg:eq("+(i+1)+")");
    }
    $(active).removeClass("active").hide();
    $(next).addClass("active").fadeIn();
},3000);
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/LsRK8/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps...edited with no button...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>delay demo</title>
<style>
div {
position: absolute;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
float: left;
}
.first {
background-color: #3f3;
left: 0;
}
.second {
background-color: #33f;
left: 80px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "div.first" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );
$( "div.second" ).slideUp( 300 ).fadeIn( 400 );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```